# Changing wordpress custom-post-type permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

How can I personalize a custom post URL in Wordpress? I've been using Custom Post Type Plugins but I want to change this URL:

```
website.com/slug/%models_cat%-%models_tag%/%postname%
```

To:

```
website.com/slug/%models_cat%-%models_tag%-%postname%
```

The second link gives me a 404 error if I change `/` to `-` on `%postname%`.

I tried to search, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing it in Settings-Permalinks?

You should be able to select Custom Structure and add any of these variables.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

EDIT:

This issue has been addressed in Wordpress Stack Exchange.

You have to edit the function.php file.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212379/dashes-instead-of-slashes-as-permalink-structure-separator

Comment: Yes, as I describe before, I'm able to change the structure with CPT Plugins, but my last problem is the '-' before %postname%, if i put '-' its give a Page not found, but work with '/' , i don't now to fix that one

Comment: Is there no example or plugins please?

Comment: Looks like you have to change it back in the functions file.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212379/dashes-instead-of-slashes-as-permalink-structure-separator

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'll look at this one and return back to you if it's ok

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you @Jhon, but i'm still stuck if it's a custom post type, the class given in this thread is working on page, I've passed my journey to handle it with custom post type but i've failed. If you can give me a class example for custom post type please ? Thank you in advance.